# cart item lost on refresh page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add item into cart using react-redux and whenever i refresh the page all my items are gone.

Here is my store.js:

```
import {
    createStore,
    applyMiddleware
} from 'redux';

import {
    composeWithDevTools
} from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
)

export default store;
```

and here is my reducer:

```
import {
    ADD_PRODUCT_BASKET,
    GET_NUMBERS_BASKET,
    LOADING,
    SUCCESS
} from '../actions/type';

const initialState = {
    products: [],
    loading: false,
    basketNumbers: 0,
    cartCost: 0,
    numbers: 0,
    inCart: false
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: [],
                    loading: true,
                    err: ''
            };

        case SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                products: action.payload,
                    loading: false,
                    err: ''
            };
        case ADD_PRODUCT_BASKET:
            let numbers = (state.numbers += 1);
            let inCart = (state.inCart = true);
            let products = state.products;
            let foundProduct = products.find(prod => prod.title === action.payload.title);

            if (foundProduct) {
                foundProduct.quantity++;
            } else {
                action.payload.quantity = 1;
                products.push(action.payload);
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                basketNumbers: state.basketNumbers + 1,
                    cartCost: state.cartCost + action.payload.price,
                    product: products,
                    numbers: numbers,
                    inCart: inCart
            };
        case GET_NUMBERS_BASKET:
            return {
                ...state
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

how can I make it stay after I refresh the page?
Here is my github project link if you want to look over my code:
https://github.com/nathannewyen/the-beuter

Comment: The redux store lives in memory and doesn't persist beyond the life of the page. If you want it to persist you need to either push it to the server or keep it in [local or session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session storage is the key here. Pretty simple to implement with Redux.
You want your initial state to load a key from session storage that is your serialized redux state.
Then subscribe a function that grabs your store state and saves it back to this session storage key. I do that with the following:

```
export const loadState = (): object | undefined => {
  try {
    const serializedState = sessionStorage.getItem('state');

    if (serializedState === null) {
      return {};
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (error) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

export const saveState = (state: object): void => {
  console.log(state);
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    sessionStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
  } catch (error) {
    // Ignore write errors
  }
};
```

In your store config do something like this:

```
const initialState = loadState();

store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(store.getState());
});
```